# Is it possible to create a portal through another portal in Co-op?

Tags: portal-2

With the introduction of the co-op levels I thought it would open up the possibility to send one of my portals through my partner's already established portals. This would allow me to create a portal in a place that might not be accessible otherwise.

I think the game is capable of supporting this behavior but when I tried it (and I have tried many times during the co-op game) all it ever did was ruin one of my partner's portals.

Are there special test chambers where this is allowed? I have not finished all of them yet.

Comment: You _can_ shoot through the portal sorta.  You just need to be standing in the portal sticking out far enough so you can shoot an exit portal and step back through before it lands.

Comment: Narbacular Drop supported this even with 1 Player, but it caused the gameplay to get a lot easier, and I imagine would make puzzles harder to make. I think it may have been a deliberate decision to not support this.

Comment: @JeffMercado No, that's Portal 1. In Portal 2, the portals basically don't have a travel time, so this isn't really possible. Unless you use that glitch with gravity adjustment, but in normal gameplay, not so much.

Comment: @lunboks: Oh so that doesn't work on Portal 2?  I have to admit, I haven't tried doing it in P2 and assumed it was the same.

Comment: fwiw, you can do this with the knock-off portal gun in Darksiders. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. There is never any case in Portal 2 where you can send a portal through another portal. As you noticed, shooting a portal at an existing portal replaces the existing portal. The behavior you are describing would be inconsistent with that, so it cannot happen.

Comment: what about [Linked portal doors](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Linked_portal_door)?

Comment: @Slothsberry in game, those do not act like portals from the player's point of view, so they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Narbacular Drop (an earlier portal-based game from the pre-Valve team) actually features this mechanic as a feature.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AM4YTEju8WY

Comment: @badp I don't think that was the kind of thing they were asking for.

Comment: ...so what is it that happens at 10.00 seconds? From the slow-mo it seems like portal through portal.

Comment: @badp If you watch the slo-mo carefully, the player goes through the portal, fires the portal gun, and then goes back through the portal into the place they just fired at. If they had fired a portal through another, they would not have ended up where they did.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Isn't that what "shoot a portal through another portal" is _all_ about?

Comment: @badp No. The player goes through the portal, and then shoots the portal at a wall. The portal projectile never goes through a portal.

Comment: Yeah, murgatroid is right. That was a nice video though.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, the game does not allow this, you will at most just end up placing another portal in the same spot.

Comment: As a minor point, I doubt this is part of the physics engine. That would deal with how objects move and react to each other in terms of mass, inertia, gravity, impulse, etc. This is almost certainly just a specific design decision, with the game engine checking if your target is a valid, portal-able (new word!) area or not.